# Bound states and extensive field configurations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, topology, topological-field-theory, instantons

1. What are [extensive field configurations](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=extensive+field+configuration) in QFT (instantons, monopoles etc.)?
2. What is the difference in description of their contribution in path integral value or in $n$-point operator functions from description of contribution of bounded states like pion?

They are both nonperturbative effects, but I don't understand how extensive field configurations appear, especially in operator formalism in QFT.

Comment: Comment to the question (v3): Did you mean [_extended_](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=extended+field+configuration) rather than [_extensive_](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=extensive+field+configuration)?

Comment: @Qmechanic : it seems to me that these two words mean the same thing

Comment: I do not understand your question. Are you asking what instantons *are*, or why one might *call* them "extended field configurations"? Also, why do you believe the description is different for PI and OF pictures? The (4D, Yang-Mills) instanton is, in both, simply a self-dual gauge field.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : "...Are you asking what instantons are, or why one might call them "extended field configurations"?.." - the second one. "...The (4D, Yang-Mills) instanton is, in both, simply a self-dual gauge field...", - and what about, for example, domain walls?